# ruby: comparison of the elements of two hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

i'm new in ruby. My question: there are 2 hashes

first: name => salary

```
people = { 
    "Jack" => 1500,
    "John" => 3000,
    "Peter" => 2500,
    "Simon" => 4000
}
```

second: car => price

```
cars = {
    "Audi" => 50000,
    "BMW" => 70000,
    "Skoda" => 30000,
    "Volvo" => 40000
}
```

And i need the code, the result is a new sorted hash "name_of_richest_man" => "the_most_expensive_car"

```
result = {
    "Simon" => "BMW",
    "John" => "Audi",
    "Peter" => "Volvo",
    "Jack" => "Skoda"
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please post some progress.

Answer (score 3):

```
people.sort_by{|_, v| v}.zip(cars.sort_by{|_, v| v})
.reverse
.map{|(k, _), (v, _)| [k, v]}.to_h
# => {"Simon"=>"BMW", "John"=>"Audi", "Peter"=>"Volvo", "Jack"=>"Skoda"}
```

Or, to make it more readable,

```
[people, cars].map{|h| h.keys.sort_by{|k| h[k]}}.transpose.reverse.to_h
# => {"Simon"=>"BMW", "John"=>"Audi", "Peter"=>"Volvo", "Jack"=>"Skoda"}
```

Comment: Com'on @sawa , he's new to ruby.. don't scare him off with that code..

Comment: @Minato Okay, I added a more readable one.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
def keys_sorted_by_decreasing_value(h)
  h.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first).reverse
end

keys_sorted_by_decreasing_value(people).zip(keys_sorted_by_decreasing_value(cars)).to_h
  #=> {"Simon"=>"BMW", "John"=>"Audi", "Peter"=>"Volvo", "Jack"=>"Skoda"}
```

Consider the calculations in `keys_sorted_by_decreasing_value`:

```
h = people
  #=> {"Jack"=>1500, "John"=>3000, "Peter"=>2500, "Simon"=>4000} 
a = h.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [["Jack", 1500], ["Peter", 2500], ["John", 3000], ["Simon", 4000]] 
b = a.map(&:first)
  #=> ["Jack", "Peter", "John", "Simon"] 
c = b.reverse
  #=> ["Simon", "John", "Peter", "Jack"] 

h = cars
  #=> {"Audi"=>50000, "BMW"=>70000, "Skoda"=>30000, "Volvo"=>40000} 
a = h.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [["Skoda", 30000], ["Volvo", 40000], ["Audi", 50000], ["BMW", 70000]] 
b = a.map(&:first)
  #=> ["Skoda", "Volvo", "Audi", "BMW"] 
d = c.reverse
  #=> ["Jack", "Peter", "John", "Simon"]
```

We then compute

```
e = c.zip(d)
  #=> [["Simon", "Jack"], ["John", "Peter"], ["Peter", "John"], ["Jack", "Simon"]]
e.to_h
  #=> {"Simon"=>"Jack", "John"=>"Peter", "Peter"=>"John", "Jack"=>"Simon"}
```